# Need to reduce the time for generation of PDF using BIPublisher

Tags: xslt, bi-publisher

Hi I have an RTF file which took around 3 hrs 15 mins time to generate the PDF report. I want to reduce the time using BI publisher in MS-word.

I expecting it should take much more less time than 3 hrs 15 mins

In this RTF I have created a repeating group within a repeating group and displayed the data with certain manipulations

[SAmple XML](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1I2Rfmrayl8i41YKlhxfTg7FmkFokCZxC/view?usp=sharing)

## Tested on Linux Machine
Machine Details :

Number of cores : 16
RAM : 65.80 GB

Comment: It looks like the conversion is done systematically wrong like turning micro-kerning (letter spacing) into single letter PostScript operations. So I would loosely copy text from the RTF and try to convert that - faster/differently. Look also at the generated size; maybe also bloated a bit.

Comment: Can you provide example @JoopEggen

Comment: Sorry, I meant to start all over, with the text, in a slight different form, say not as RTF, as RTF with clean settings, etcetera. Till now noone experienced answered, so you probably have to tackle the cause by experimenting. It should be easy (though costing time) by varying settings to find what makes it slow.